# Check credentials of SQL Login

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I can create an SQL login account for an user as follows:

```
CREATE LOGIN [myusername] WITH PASSWORD = N'mypassword', CHECK_POLICY= OFF;
```

I can check e.g. if 'myusername' exists:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'myusername'
```

But how can I check if 'myusername' and a password 'wrong_password' supplied by the user are correct?

My solution in C# is with the help of Roger as follows:

```
    private static bool SqlLoginExists(string username)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;" + "Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        connection.Open();

        string sql_command = "SELECT count(*) FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'" + username + "'";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql_command, connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.GetValue(0).ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool CheckSQLCredentialsIfLoginExists(string username, string password)
    {
        bool SqlUserExists = SqlLoginExists(username);

        if (SqlUserExists)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;" + "User id=" + username+";Password=" + password +";";
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                connection.Dispose();
                return false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return true; // it is not a problem for me if account does not exist (as it will be created later), I am only worried about the case when the credentials are wrong
        }
    }
```

Comment: If they weren't, the user wouldn't have been able to login in the first place. Do you mean "how do I authenticate a user who's not logged in"? Because if that's your question, you are probably solving the wrong problem -- what are you trying to achieve? Do you need to do something on behalf of the user, perhaps?

Comment: It looks like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why you ever want to check it manually? SQL server pretty good checks authentication it by itself - so what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Will each of your users have a SQL login?  This wouldn't necessarily be a very common usage.  It would tend to be either there are mapped domain accounts, or you have a single SQL login and you manage user logins through your application code using a separate user table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `pwdcompare()` function:

```
select pwdcompare(N'MyWrongPassword', sl.password_hash) as [Match]
from master.sys.sql_logins sl
where sl.name = N'MyLogin';
```

However, there is a very big chance you are working in a wrong direction - it is more correct to try and establish connection using supplied credentials.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I am looking for. The reason why I want to do that is because the user provides SQL credentials in an installation dialog BEFORE the database even exists. Thus I can directly throw an error if the user entered an already existing account but a wrong password rather than throwing an error during the installation.

Comment: Still no difference. SQL Server logins and passwords are stored in the `master` database which always exists in any given SQL Server instance. You can try to connect to it instead of your nonexistent-at-this-point database, the result will be exactly the same. Well, except that in your case you need the `control server` permission - otherwise the `password_hash` column in `sys.sql_logins` will be unavailable.

Comment: Thanks again. I posted my solution (in C#) according to your suggestions in the question post. I basically check first if the login exists using and then try to connect using the supplied username and password in order to find out if the credentials are OK.

Comment: So you must need... a different elevated account to connect beforehand to actually run `pwdcompare`? it might be simpler of you just try to connect with the given credentials and catch a failure

Comment: @user1810304, I see. So you want to distinguish between a non-existent login and a login with incorrect credentials supplied. In that case, your initial approach is indeed justifiable.